# How do I get a bigger sheet size in Altium, updating current one?

Tags: schematics, altium, cad

I have a schematic sheet and I need more free space on it. The actual size is A4. I have right-clicked in the sheet, went to Preferences and changed the Sheet Size from A4 to A3 but that does not make new free space appear. How can I get a bigger sheet without losing my current design and start a new empty one? I am using v21.5 and my memory tells me that in previous versions that was the way.

Comment: The preferences will only apply when new schematic sheets are created. This comment plus the answer provided by Rev should help you out.

Comment: You can also create a new sheet as an empty A3 then copy all of your schematic to it, save it and delete the A4 version.

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com

Comment: @citizen this would delete the designators numbering

Comment: @Developing Electronics. So you can spend a few minutes manually adding them ... that shouldn't be so bad. Just make sure you choose the A3 size from the start to avoid this issue !

Answer (score 1):

From the property panel (View->Panels->Properties) you should be able to change the sheet size.

[image]

In the example I switched from an A4 template to an A3 template and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: It does not solve the problem. It changes but now its smaller even with A2

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics What do you mean by "now it's smaller?" What is smaller, the sheet size? What are the width and height dimensions reported under the template selection?

Comment: I changed it to A3 or A2 and the sheet size is smaller and all the blocks are now outsite it

Comment: With European sheet sizes (A2, A3, A4, etc.) the smaller numbers are larger. If the schematic sheet size was not large enough using, for example, A4, then changing to A3 or A2 should have made the sheet larger. You should be able to verify the sheet dimensions just below the template selection pulldown menu.